# Are there any Designers for XForms?

Tags: ide, designer, xforms

I am searching for a designer or  an IDE which can be used to create XForms by dragging and dropping elements.

I found visual XForms designer by IBM at http://www.alphaworks.ibm.com/tech/vxd .
But it is not that user friendly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [Orbeon Form Builder](http://orbeon.com/forms/orbeon-form-builder). See also the [FAQ](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/orbeon-forms-faq/faq-orbeon-form-builder). It's open source.

It's not strictly a general-purpose XForms editor, but it's a form editor that deals with XHTML+XForms+extensions. If you don't want to use Orbeon Forms to process the forms generated, you could transform the result e.g. with XSLT.

(Disclaimer: I work on Orbeon Forms.)

Answer (score 1):

I am also trying to find a good XForm designer. One that I found useful is [Vellum](https://github.com/dimagi/Vellum) - It is an XForms form designer written purely in Javascript and it's Open source.

Vellum targets modern browsers. IE8 and earlier are not supported. It is used in production by [Commcare](http://www.commcarehq.org).

Answer (score 0):

[Oryx](http://code.google.com/p/oryx-editor/) used to offer one: http://bpt.hpi.uni-potsdam.de/Oryx/XForms. The current code is unmaintained, but there is a [github fork](https://github.com/IAAS/oryx-editor/).